# Load a huge amount of factory before test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

In my Rails project, I have a factory file that contains a lot of factories like this :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :'59000', class: PostalCode do
    value "59000"
    name "toto"
  end
  factory :'59800', class: PostalCode do
    value "59800"
    name "toto"
  end
  factory :'59777', class: PostalCode do
    value "59777"
    name "toto"
  end
  factory :'59910', class: PostalCode do
    value "59910"
    name "toto"
  end
  factory :'59170', class: PostalCode do
    value "59170"
    name "toto"
  end
  factory :'59155', class: PostalCode do
    value "59155"
    name "toto"
  end
  factory :'59510', class: PostalCode do
    value "59510"
    name "toto"
  end
  factory :'59259', class: PostalCode do
    value "59259"
    name "toto"
  end

  ...

end
```

Do you know how I can build/create all the factories this file contains before the test suite ?

Thanks,
Jules

Comment: Maybe you should consider fixtures instead of factories.

Comment: Why ? I'm ok with factories !

Comment: Using factories is a lot of extra creates.  Fixtures will be faster

Comment: Here is one reference: http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/7-reasons-why-im-sticking-with-minitest-and-fixtures-in-rails/

Comment: I'm fine with RSpec. I think it's a great unit test framework. 
If others think that minitest (or other) is better for them, I'm happy they could use it but I'm currently fine with RSpec, FactoryGirl, Capybara, etc. so I will not change. 
Thanks for the link.

Jules

Comment: rspec works with fixtures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
before do
  %w(59000 59259 59510).each do |code|
    create(code)
  end
end
```

**Solution 2:**

```
before do
  FactoryGirl.factories.select { |factory| 
    factory.send(:class_name) == PostalCode 
  }.each{|factory| FactoryGirl.create(factory.name) }
end
```

**Solution 3:**

Some variation of previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 is soooo great ! Thanks a lot !

I just put it like it :

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryGirl.factories.select { |factory|
      factory.send(:class_name) == PostalCode
    }.each{|factory| FactoryGirl.create(factory.name) }
  end
```

in my rails_helper config file and all my postal codes are seed in my database.

Again, thank you !

Jules